# Is there an easy example of a variety that is not rational? ${}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, birational-geometry

I saw a lot of examples of varieties which are rational, now I was also wondering if there was a simple example of a variety that is not rational. Sadly I didn't find that much online, is it maybe hard to find them?

Comment: How about an elliptic curve?

Comment: You might be interested in https://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Spring/18.726/l_7.pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

You can check that in char $\ne 3$ the curve $x^3 + y^3 = 1$ is not rational.

$\bf{Added:}$

By a sign change, reduce to $x^3 + y^3 + 1 = 0$ (easier to deal with). Now, assume that we have a rational parametrization $(x,y) = (\frac{P(t)}{R(t)}, \frac{Q(t)}{R(t)})$, with $P$, $Q$, $R$ polynomials. We get
$$P^3(t) + Q^3(t) + R^3(t) = 0$$

Assume that $\operatorname{gcd}(P, Q, R) = 1$, otherwise divide by the common divisor. Now, since the parametrization is non-trivial, at least one of the $P$, $Q$, $R$ is non-constant. Take the derivative in the equality above and get
$$3 P'(t) P^2(t) + 3 Q'(t) Q^2(t) + 3 R'(t) R^2(t) = 0$$

Since the char is $\ne 3$, we may divide by $3$. Now we get two linear equations in the vector $(P^2(t), Q^2(t), R^2(t))$. It follows that this vector is proportional to
$$(P(t), Q(t), R(t)) \times (P'(t), Q'(t), R'(t))$$
Note that this above vector is $\ne 0$, otherwise $P$, $Q$, $R$ have constant quotients, not possible. Also note that the vector $(P^2(t), Q^2(t), R^2(t))$ has relatively prime entries. It follows that
$$M(t) \cdot (P^2(t), Q^2(t), R^2(t) ) =   (P(t), Q(t), R(t)) \times (P'(t), Q'(t), R'(t))$$
where $M(t)$ is a polynomial. But now we have problems with the degree, since if $P(t)$ is then the polynomial of largest degree then  $M(t) \cdot P^2(t)  \not =  Q(t) R'(t) - R(t) Q'(t)$, contradiction.

Note: This works  for the curve $a x^n + b y^n +c = 0$, $a b c \ne 0$, $n\ge 3$, char $\not \mid n$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let $A$ be a [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) ( in our case $k[t]$, where $k$ is the basic field), $K$ its field of fractions. Let $m\ge 2$ be a natural number, and consider $K^m$, $m$-size vectors with components in $K$ ( here $m=3$).  Now, let $v \in A^m\subset K^m$, with the [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of its entries $1$, and let   $A^m \ni w = \alpha v$ proportional to $v$.  Then $\alpha \in A$. (for us $v = (P^2, Q^2, R^2)$, $w = (P,Q,R) \times (P', Q', R')$ ).

Indeed, we have $w_i = \alpha v_i$ for all $i$. If $e_p(\alpha) < 0$ for some prime of $A$, and $i$ is one of the components for which $e_p(v_i) =0$ (  the components of $v$ are relatively prime ), we would get $e_p(w_i) < 0$, contradiction.  Another proof (if the domain is [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), like $k[t]$) take $\sum c_i v_i = 1$, and so $\alpha = \alpha \cdot 1 = \alpha \cdot (\sum c_i v_i) = \sum c_i w_i \in A$.

Comment: How would you do so? I would say that the meromorphic 1-form $\frac{dy}x$ has no pole on $y^2=x^3+1$ to contradict that the function field is $\cong \Bbb{C}(z)$.

Comment: @reuns: Added some details. It is the proof given in the book by Shafarevich, AG.  Your proof would work for more general cases.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I had to read your answer 10 times but now I can see it is slightly more elementary than looking at $dx/y$ on $y^2=x^3+1$.

Comment: @reuns: Thanks!  It uses the fact that $k[t[$ is UFD, so every vector in $k(t)^3$ has a unique (up to units) reduced representative in $k[t]^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is one thing I don‘t understand: You say that these two vectors are proportional, but how does that imply the existence of $M$? Or why is $M$ a polynomial and not a quotient of polynomials?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not quite sure why exactly we can find such a $M$. I understand that the cross-product is a solution of this linear system of equations. Also, since the matrix has rank 2, the kernel must be 1d, hence, if we have one particular solution, the whole solution space is spanned by this particular solution. So are we considering $K(t)$ as a Vector space over itself, hence the general solution set must be of the form $K(t) \cdot $ particular solution, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Thanks! But I think I was more wondering, why exactly we have this proportionality between the vector $(P(t)^2, Q(t)^2, R(t)^2)$ and the cross-product vector. I understand why the cross-product is a solution of the linear system of equations, but why does every solution then have the form $M(t) \cdot$ cross-product? Why is there not another solution of a different form? Is it because the kernel has only 1 dimension?

Comment: @LinearAlgebruh: Yes, the kernel is $1$ dim because the matrix has rank $2$, and this because the two vectors in the cross product are not proportional,  can't happen ( another fact that has to be checked, although not that hard).

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I think i finally understood it